# Smotri Videos on iPhone?

Tags: php, jquery, html, video

If you guys think it's possible to use a video from Smotri.com in an embed and make it work for iphone on your website. Becuse if you go to the smotri url, it will work on iphone.

I have tried wrapping the hole website in a iframe but it moves me to smotri.com instead of showing it in iframe.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should contact their forums/support if they have any. From the looks of it, they do have their own iPhone app, so there must be a way (that they may or may not keep to themselves).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does iPhone even support Flash?

Anyway, you don't need to do IFrame, just embed the flash part like so.

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://pics.smotri.com/player.swf?b6e93d762830bd9aa5c8d1e4e668be97" width="640" height="360" id="video93707" name="video93707" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" quality="high" wmode="opaque" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" base="http://pics.smotri.com" flashvars="file=v23756861434&amp;autoStart=true&amp;logo=false&amp;auth=0&amp;str_lang=rus&amp;settings=http://pics.smotri.com/cskins/blue/skin_ng.xml&amp;xmldatasource=http://pics.smotri.com/cskins/blue/skin_ng.xml&amp;context=%7B%22c_id%22%3A2375686%2C%22c_uid%22%3A9061678%2C%22c_rubric%22%3A%221%22%2C%22c_doubtful%22%3A0%2C%22c_tags%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22c_mod%22%3A%5B-1%5D%2C%22u_id%22%3A%22g_14cbe120eaa2eb7c92025929eedf1494_a871%22%2C%22u_ip%22%3A%2283.99.236.218%22%2C%22u_auth%22%3A0%2C%22p_pr_id%22%3A13%2C%22c_section%22%3A%5B%2215%22%2C%2214%22%5D%7D">
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kWm7g/

Comment: It dont support flash, but I think smotri checks that if device = iphone then do html5 or something try it :) Go to a video link on your iphone it will work fine, but if you use their embed code and but it on your website it will not work for iphone.

Comment: Attempting to embed a Flash object will definitely not work on an iOS device.

Comment: Can I iframe it then?

Comment: @Frank Emulate iPhone browser, go to their site, see the source code for embedded video and copy it. It should work then.

Comment: Well I did check the source before but then I didnt check it very  
thoroughly but now I found the real video file when i checked it again! Thanks! ^^